# JQuery Change event not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My change function works great for select controls that are built into the page initially, but when I dynamically add a select control, the change function won't fire.

```
<select name="SUBJ" class="SUBJ" id="SUBJ_-9">
   <option value="1">First item</option>
   <option value="2">Second item</option>
</select>

$j('.SUBJ').change(function () {

    alert("foo");

}
```

I'm wondering after I dynamically add the control:

```
$j("tbody > tr:last").prev().before(strAppend);
```

do I need to call any function to associate the event watcher/handler with the control?

Any other ideas? Tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are generating HTML dynamically with Jquery, so try **event delegation** as shown :-

```
$j('body').on('change','.SUBJ',function() {
    alert("foo");
});
```

OR

```
$j(document).on('change','.SUBJ',function() {
    alert("foo");
});
```

[Reference.](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler)

Comment: Many thanks, Kartikeya and suchit. That did it! You guys rock!

Comment: @SlimJim..happy to help you..:)

Answer (score 2):

you need to bind the event.try like this:

```
$j('body').on('change','.SUBJ',function() {

    alert("foo");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is a little off, you're missing a ')' at the end. It should look like

```
$j('.SUBJ').change(function () {

     alert("foo");

});
```